# How to parse parameters that sent jquery table

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, datatable

I writing a simple Spring MVC web application that use [JQuery DataTable](http://datatables.net/) on the client-side. DataTable using server-side processing mode. The DataTable make request  with parameters(in my case):

```
draw:1
columns[0][data]:name
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:type
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:action
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
```

I don't know how can i parse parameters like `columns[i][data]`, `columns[i][name]`,  `columns[i][searchable]`, etc. The reason is why, because I don't know how many table columns I will have. How to solve this problem?
This is my Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getImageWrappers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getImageWrappers(@RequestParam Integer draw,
                                                 @RequestParam Integer start,
                                                 @RequestParam Integer length,
                                                 @RequestParam(value = "search[value]") String searchText){
    }
```

and DataTable configuration:

```
$('#imageWrapperTable').DataTable({
            columns:[
                {"data" : "name"},
                {"data" : "type"},
                {"data" : "action"}
            ],
            "processing": true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '/getImageWrappers.json',
                type: 'POST'
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out by adding this code

```
$('#imageWrapperTable').DataTable({
        columns:[
            {"data" : "name"},
            {"data" : "type"},
            {"data" : "action"}
        ],
        "processing": true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/getImageWrappers.json',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: function(d){
                 //add your custom param here
                 d.name = "zxbing";

                 //this will put all query strings to a json object string
                 return JSON.stringify(d);
            }
        }
    });
```

In this way, you just need to transfer only a query string to JSON object on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

In a json array I would do something like this with jquery:

```
function displayData(x) {
x.success(function(data) {

    $.each(data.columns, function(i, paramenter) {
        $.each(parameter, function(a, b) {
            $('#somediv').append('column'+parameter+' -> data: '+b+' ');
        });
    });

}),
x.error(function(data) {
    //error message
})
}//end displayData
```

So you can loop through your array, but you gotta play around with it, I haven't tested it but in general that is the idea. Hope it helps.